# how to set limit on number of tables in a database in sqlite?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite

I have a win-form application that reads a file and stores the data in the file into a table.But every time I read data from the file i need to store it in a new table.I want to set limit for number of tables in my database to 50 and if that limit is crossed, I want to delete the first table that was created and insert the new table at the last.

How can i implement this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not simply delete the temporary table after you have finished using it?

Comment: When you say "a new table", do you really mean "a new row in an existing table"?

Comment: @BenRobinson.....i can't delete the old tables because i need them...it's one of the features of my application

Comment: @Kjartan......by new table i mean a new table not a new row.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design.  Why not keep all the records in the same table along with an Id identifying which import the record came from? Then you could have a trigger on insert to delete rows that are < 50 of the row being inserted.

Comment: I seocnd @Kjartan's comment, do you really mean new table? And if you do, consider doing a single table with a "Table Identifier" autoincrement column to identify the "tables". Would make your operatin easier (and faster).

Comment: @MathewCollins.....actually i cannot store data in the same table as i have other features that depend on the table and any editing done on the table will effect them also.

Comment: @Kratos when you say any editing will affect other features do you mean editing of the data, or editing of the table schema?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish.....i mean editing of data....adding any data will lead to wrong result from my application

Comment: Well yeah, you'll have to make a change to your application to read from one table and use the Id column to identify which records to display, but that's likely to be a much simpler change than managing 50 separate tables.  What happens if you want to change the table schema? You're going to edit every single one?

Comment: @Kratos then I think you need to edit the way you retrieve the data from your application so this doesn't happen. Dynamically creating tables seems a very bad design plan.

Answer (score 3):

How you could handle this:

1) create a table which holds the data about the tables, name/ creation date

2) your insert data / make new table proc then reads from this table, if there are <50 entries it just creates a new table and adds it to the list, if 50 tables it takes the one with the earliest creation date, drops it and then uses that space to create a new table and add it to the list

Now having said that, I think from a design point of view this is a very bad way to handle this.

I would personally have one table to hold your data (assuming all the data imported is of the same type / uses the same columns etc) then just tie each document together with an  ID and creation date. When you have 50 unique IDs you delete the records with the lowest ID and insert your record with the next available ID number.